# How to replace two specific element values in an XML file within a specific element block?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've this XML file:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ApplicationsToCheck xmlns = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/StoreAppraisalSvc/SharedResources/Schemas/HealthCheck/Schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/StoreAppraisalSvc/SharedResources/Schemas/HealthCheck/Schema.xsd ../Schemas/HealthCheck/HealthCheckSchema.xsd">
<Application>
<ApplicationName>AccountsPayableAdapter</ApplicationName>
<HAMode>NA</HAMode>
<AppPortList>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>
<Port>57611</Port>
</HostPort>
</AppPortList>
</Application>
<Application>
<ApplicationName>CorpCredit</ApplicationName>
<HAMode>LB</HAMode>
<AppPortList>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>
<Port>57250</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP02</HostName>
<Port>57250</Port>
</HostPort>
</AppPortList>
</Application>
<Application>
<ApplicationName>CustomerSvcV1_0</ApplicationName>
<HAMode>LB</HAMode>
<AppPortList>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>
<Port>57632</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>
<Port>57641</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP02</HostName>
<Port>57632</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP02</HostName>
<Port>57641</Port>
</HostPort>
</AppPortList>
</Application>
</ApplicationsToCheck>
```

I want to change the values of two **HostName** elements using a Windows script to have finally value `ESBBWSVCP03` instead of `ESBBWSVCP01` and `ESBBWSVCP04` instead of `ESBBWSVCP02` in the file, but **only** within element **ApplicationName** with value `CorpCredit`.

**EDIT:** Here is what I have tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set sourcefile=d:\CorpApplicationsToCheck.xml
set tempfile=d:\tempfile.txt
set oldtoken=ESBBWSVCP01
set newtoken=ESBBWSVCP03
type nul>%tempfile% for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%sourcefile%) do (
    set line=%%l
    set line=!line:%oldtoken%=%newtoken%!
    echo !line!>>tempfile.txt
)
del %sourcefile%
move %tempfile% %sourcefile%
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command interpreter executing batch files is not designed for processing XML files. There are script interpreters which have built-in features for XML file editing/modifying.

By the way: The first two lines of the XML file should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApplicationsToCheck xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/StoreAppraisalSvc/SharedResources/Schemas/HealthCheck/Schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/StoreAppraisalSvc/SharedResources/Schemas/HealthCheck/Schema.xsd ../Schemas/HealthCheck/HealthCheckSchema.xsd">
```

There should be no space between attribute name, equal sign and attribute value.

However, this task can be easily done using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid for replacing strings in files using a regular expression.

The file `D:\CorpApplicationsToCheck.xml` can be updated with the following batch file with `jrepl.bat` being in same directory as this batch file.

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(<ApplicationName>CorpCredit</ApplicationName>(?:[\s\S](?!<HostName>))+?[\s\S]<HostName>ESBBWSVCP0)1(</HostName>(?:[\s\S](?!<HostName>))+?[\s\S]<HostName>ESBBWSVCP0)2" "$13$24" /M /F D:\CorpApplicationsToCheck.xml /O -
```

The explanation for the regular expression search string:

`(`...`)` ... marking/capturing group. The string found by the expression between the first parenthesis pair is back-referenced in replace string with `$1` to keep this part of found string in file without a modification. The search string contains a second parenthesis pair for capturing a second part of the found string for keeping unmodified on replace referenced with `$2` in the replace string.

`<ApplicationName>CorpCredit</ApplicationName>` ... find case-sensitive this string as written in the batch file.

`(?:[\s\S](?!<HostName>))+?[\s\S]` ... find any whitespace character OR any non whitespace character which means any character including newline characters 1 or more times non-greedy up to the **next** occurrence of starting tag `<HostName>`. `(?:`...`)` defines a non marking group used here to specify an expression on which the multiplier `+` should be applied non-greedy as defined with `?` after the multiplier. `(?!`...`)` is a negative lookahead. This expression is for matching everything after the fixed string specified before up to **next** and not **any** starting tag `<HostName>`.

`<HostName>ESBBWSVCP0` ... this string should be found next as written here.

`1` .. the next character must be this character which is outside the marking group as the target is to replace it with `3`.

Then the second marking group with nearly same expression follows with `2` outside the marking group to be replaced with `4`.

So the expression searches for the block:

```xml
<ApplicationName>CorpCredit</ApplicationName>
<HAMode>LB</HAMode>
<AppPortList>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>
<Port>57250</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP02
```

If this multi-line string (block) could be found using `jrepl.bat` with option `/M` (multi-line), it is replaced by the block:

```xml
<ApplicationName>CorpCredit</ApplicationName>
<HAMode>LB</HAMode>
<AppPortList>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP03</HostName>
<Port>57250</Port>
</HostPort>
<HostPort>
<HostName>ESBBWSVCP04
```

All other `<HostName>ESBBWSVCP01</HostName>` and `<HostName>ESBBWSVCP02</HostName>` in the file are ignored by this search and replace.